# Библиотека или Api для распознавания лиц C#

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, opencv

Есть желание глубже "пощупать" компьютерное зрение. Имеется пару наработок на OpenCV - EMGU с захватом лиц. А вот какой API, библиотеки или фреймворк для C# выбрать по распознаванию и сравнению лиц с сохраненной фотографией в поточном видеостриме. Нет понимания, что выбрать? Может MS Oxford, Azure Face API - но там насколько я понял необходим токкен(возможно платный). Приложение хочу написать десктопное на WPF.Буду признателен любой информации и помощи.

Comment: [Getting Started with Face API in C# Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiincsharptutorial)

Comment: По стоимости - [Pricing details(Face API)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/face-api/)

Comment: Вы советуете Face API, насколько я понял там много алгоритмов как на детектирование, так и на отображения эмоций, пола и сравнивания лиц с фото? Если да, то такой вопрос(возможно глупый, не судите строго - только разбираюсь), сервис работает с подключением к интернет? Или через Nuget пакеты библиотек?

Comment: @JDo А вы код смотрели? `private readonly IFaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("_key_", "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0");` Явно говорит о подключение к серверу. Ну а вообще это Azure, облачные технологии майкнософт, которые так или иначе требуют работу через интернет.

Comment: Не обратил внимание. Спасибо! А есть библиотеки для оффлайн работы?

Comment: Для оффлайн, наверное, лучше OpenCV не найти, есть также [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com), [Accord](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/R_Project_Accord_NET.htm) . Но в ML я не специалист

Comment: Просто в Open CV я не нашел как можно сделать Face Recognition. Детектирование лица получается.